# html5 set up div width bigger than body width

Tags: html, width

I set `body {margin: 0 auto; width: 900px;}`

100% width of display

I want one of `div` (or `section`) inside that body to be 100% of display (not its parent 900px, but more).
What styles should be applied for this div?

```
<body>
<div>
900px width of this text
</div>
<div style="???">
the whole 100% length of display
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it if you set a width on `<body>`. I'd leave `<body>` alone and do something like:

```
div {
  width: 900px;
}
div.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and then make sure your content is a series of `<div>`s, some of which have `class="fullwidth"` (such elements need to be non-nested, since for a nested element "100%" will be interpreted as "100% of the containing element" which in turn works out to "100% of 900px").

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `<div>` to be 100% of the screen width, you must set `display` property in CSS.

```
display:block;
```

[An example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Comment: I have a similar problem as the original author's. I just tried display:block in my footer div, which is within a fixed-width body. The div does not display as the full screen width, but only as 100% of the width of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position:absolute;` which would keep it from inheriting the width from the body.

Comment: I thought about that solutione, thank you for pointing that. But I'm not sure position:absolute is a good solution to make a complex layout. If I make position:absolute, I don't know how to display footer below that div with absolute position.